# iOS - Button tap animation in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

So I have a main view that is a UIScrollView, and I add all of my elements (UIButtons, UITextFields, UILabels etc. etc.) to it.

The problem I am having, is that when I go to tap a button, the button will perform the action(s) that it is supposed to, however I will not see the pressed animation occur.
I can only see the animation if I press and hold for about half a second.

I believe this has something to do with the fact that the UIScrollView seems to think I am trying to scroll at first, but I am not sure.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I want the button animation to occur instantly when I press it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the delaysContentTouches set to YES (the default). Per the UIScrollView documentation:

> `delaysContentTouches` A Boolean value that determines whether the
>   scroll view delays the handling of touch-down gestures.
>
> `@property(nonatomic) BOOL delaysContentTouches`
>
> Discussion
>
> **If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view delays handling the
>   touch-down gesture until it can determine if scrolling is the intent.**
>   If the value is NO , the scroll view immediately calls
>   touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:. The default value is YES.

Set this property to NO on your UIScrollView and the touches will be passed instantly to your elements.